# How to move the second child in my nav menu with CSS

Tags: html, css, menu, navigation

I have trouble customizing my navigation menu in CSS and am looking for anyone who can help me with this. I would like my second child element in the navigation menu on its new line and not underneath the first child ([see picture for explanation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFdO4.jpg)).

A working example for this menu is at www.plcphilly.com, any help for this would be great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to add the following code into your stylesheet.

```
.navbar .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu li {
    display: inline-block;
}
```